# How to use keyboard shortcut to copy formatting in Mac Word

Tags: macos, ms-office, shortcut

According to [this microsoft support page](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/copy-formatting-in-word-for-mac-7a5e253e-d951-4fee-bbe5-1c77a90171de) (shown in the animated gif at right below)

> To use keyboards shortcuts to copy formatting, press COMMAND + SHIFT + C to copy the formatting, select the text that you want to apply the formatting to, and then press COMMAND + SHIFT + V to paste the formatting

However, as shown in the animated gif below (click for better detail), it does not work for me. I describe what I'm doing with the keyboard with the text in black, blue, and red.

Notice at the end that I am able to paste format using the format painter tool, but *my goal is to use keyboard shortcuts* to do this. To demonstrate that this is not due additional custom shortcuts on my system, I have the shortcuts portion of the System Preferences open and you can also see the normal paste shortcuts in the Edit menu during the animated gif.

[image]

I'm using an updated Microsoft Word for Mac version 16.29.1 on an Office 365 subscription with macOS 10.14.6.

Comment: @klanomath I addressed SysPrefs in the lower left part of the image. But, I realized that I should also consider the keyboard shortcut setting within Word itself (Tools>Customize Keyboard...). I noticed that I had shortcuts assigned to both cmd-shift-C and cmd-shift-V. So the fact that it works for you helped me solve that part. Now how about the other part I mention in the bounty: "I often use the Paint Format tool to repeatedly apply the format by a double click on the button, and I'd really like to see a keyboard shortcut to toggle that mode" Is this possible? Please post as an **answer**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If a shortcut doesn't work as expected (i.e. as mentioned in the help text/manual) check whether you configured the same shortcut as global shortcut in System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts. If you set up a "concurrent" shortcut it may also occur in Services, Screenshot etc.

Also check the app's preferences whether you set up custom shortcuts which override the app's default shortcuts.

---

It's not necessary to set up a custom shortcut for Word's *Paint Format tool* double click.

The logic behind the *Paint Format tool* button compared to the default shortcuts works like this:

1. Choosing some formatted text and clicking *Paint Format tool* (1st click) equals <kbd>cmd</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> (copy format)
2. Choosing another part of the text ("2nd click") equals choosing some text and <kbd>cmd</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> (paste format) - the *Paint Format tool* button is resetted afterwards!
3. Choosing some formatted text and double-clicking *Paint Format tool* and formatting several other text parts afterwards equals <kbd>cmd</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> and several <kbd>cmd</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>V</kbd>.

If you copy a text format/style with <kbd>cmd</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> (**or** with the 1st click on *Paint Format tool*!) it will remain in the "format/style pasteboard" until you copy another text format/style or quit Word.

You can apply it with *Paint Format tool* only once (2nd click) but with the shortcut as often as required.